# .NET XML Support In Redirect (301,302)

Tags: .net, xml, redirect

I build a software to download files from the web using XML files that the user loads into the software in order to download the files directly from the software.
This is an example for XML file that the user will load in order to download the latest update from MSE(Anti Virus):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<Software Name="MSE 64">
    <Address Name = "http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=121721&arch=x64">
        <File Name = "mpam-feX64.exe" Store = "yes"/>
        <File Name = "mpas-fe.exe" Store = "yes"/>
        <File Name = "mpam-fe.exe" Store = "yes"/>
    </Address>
</Software>
```

The problem that i'm facing is that sometimes the Address is an address to a redirect url so i need to be able to support redirect in my XML software, How Can I Do it ?

This Is The Code:(a part of it anyway)

```
static void Update(XElement stage, string folder, string contextAddress, string contextFile)
    {
        switch (stage.Name.LocalName.ToLower())
        {
            case "file":
                string currentFile;
                if (stage.Attribute("Name") != null) currentFile = stage.Attribute("Name").Value;
                else if (stage.Attribute("Pattern") != null)
                {
                    Regex re = new Regex(stage.Attribute("Pattern").Value, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline |
                        (stage.Attribute("Instance") != null && stage.Attribute("Instance").Value.ToLower() == "last" ? RegexOptions.RightToLeft : 0));
                    Match m = re.Match(File.ReadAllText(contextFile));
                    if (!m.Success) throw new FileNotFoundException("A file name couldn't be matched");
                    currentFile = m.Groups.Count > 0 ? m.Groups[0].Value : m.Value;
                }
                else break;

                contextFile = Path.Combine(folder, Path.GetFileName(currentFile).Length > 0 ? Path.GetFileName(currentFile) : Path.GetFileName(contextAddress));
                string tempFile = Path.GetTempFileName();
                try
                {
                    using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
                    { wc.DownloadFile(Uri.IsWellFormedUriString(currentFile, UriKind.Absolute) ? currentFile : contextAddress + '/' + currentFile, tempFile); }
                    lock (stage.Ancestors("Software").First().Annotation<System.Threading.Timer>())
                    { File.Delete(contextFile); File.Move(tempFile, contextFile); }
                }
                finally { File.Delete(tempFile); }
                break;

            case "address":
                if (stage.Attribute("Name") != null)
                {
                    string currentAddress = stage.Attribute("Name").Value;
                    contextAddress = Uri.IsWellFormedUriString(currentAddress, UriKind.Absolute) ? currentAddress : contextAddress + '/' + currentAddress;
                }
                break;

            case "software": break;

            default: return;
        }
```

(Support HTTP response status code 301 & 302).

Thank You

Comment: I just see XML. And XML can't download files, so where is the code doing that?

Comment: Can you show us your invoke code?

Answer (score 1):

You need to read the HTTP status code and act on it.

Edit:

You can catch the statuscode from your WebClient and create a switch that sets the new url based on the Location given by the HTTP response.

Comment: I understand that, i need to know how can i do it exactly?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using WebClient.DownloadFile() it will automatically follow redirects.

Comment: I'm using it, but it doesnt follow redirects maybe i need to configure something ?

Comment: WebClient has a WebRequest object inside it with `AllowAutoRedirect=true`. You can check that it isnt disabled in your code for some reason. Are you sure the page sends a proper redirect?

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code:

```
HttpWebRequest myHttpWebRequest=(HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=121721&arch=x64");    
myHttpWebRequest.MaximumAutomaticRedirections=1;
myHttpWebRequest.AllowAutoRedirect=true;
HttpWebResponse myHttpWebResponse=(HttpWebResponse)myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse();
```

I tried it at asp.net, it works fine, not sure if works fine at your application. So please let me know if it works fine at your application, maybe I can help you to debug it